# Forcing action right before application termination

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 libraries.

The first one downloads some web pages and stores them in more "parsable" way to some files on disc.

The other relies on the files and therefore it needs some sort of verification that all the files were downloaded and processed correctly.

I couldn't figure out any other solution than the first library creating something like `setup.txt` where it would append messages such as `$"Exception {e.GetType()} - {pathToDirectoryWithCorruptedFiles}"` or `$"Success - {pathToDirectoryWithCorrectFiles}"`.

I don't think this is the correct way, because after exceptions like `StackOverFlowException` or `OutOfMemoryException` and after termination with `Ctrl + C` the program is terminated and so there is no time to do something.

Is there any way of writing something or storing some information after these exceptions of after `Ctrl + C` ? Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - one application downloads the file, and the second processes it. You need to notify the second application that the file download was completed successfully. Correct me if I'm wrong. I think it is better to use a message broker to send a message from the first application to the secondю This message will notify the second one that the work is completed without error and the second application can start working. Rabbitmq or Kafka should do the trick.
Or if there are exactly libraries - you can use events to notify the second library that file was downloaded successfully.

Comment: One library downloads the file(s) the second one will work with downloaded data but not necessarily at the same time as the first. 

Example : first library downloaded files A1,...,An Monday. Second library works with the files Tuesday, Wednesday and so on. It has to look for data and find out if it is corrupted or not. Right now there is file "setup.txt" which contains names of all directories in the current one and a note if they're corrupted or not.

Comment: So why don't you write to "setup.txt" only the names of correct files? Or if you need to store all of the files in "setup.txt" maybe it is good idea to store a "corrupted" flag? Maybe it is good idea to use a json in "setup.txt" like that
{ 
   "files":[ 
      { 
         "fileDirectory":"C:/Documents/A1",
         "isCorrupted":false
      },
      { 
         "fileDirectory":"C:/Documents/A2",
         "isCorrupted":true
      }
   ]
}

Comment: And according to your exceptions I think that after downloading and before saving you should write into file information about new file and set "isCorrupted" to false and after successful saving you should change it to true